# SQL Select multiple rows with same column values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table:

> ```
> column1   column2    column3        column4 
> ---------------------------------------------
> 1          53          6527          111
> 2          53          6527          111
> 3          53          6527          111
> 4          53          6527          111
> 5          53          6527          222
> 6          53          6527          222
> 7          53          6527          333
> 8          53          6527          333
> 9          53          6527          444
> 10         53          6527          444
> 11         53          6527          444
> 12         53          6527          444
> ```

I need `select` if exists three rows with some column4 value if exists just two then two or one. Max is three. After `select` i need get result like this:

> ```
> column1   column2    column3        column4 
> ---------------------------------------------
> 1          53          6527          111
> 2          53          6527          111
> 3          53          6527          111
> 5          53          6527          222
> 6          53          6527          222
> 7          53          6527          333
> 8          53          6527          333
> 9          53          6527          444
> 10         53          6527          444
> 11         53          6527          444
> ```

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Comment: Oh.. Sorry i fix it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using SQL Server you can use [ranking function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)s to get the result:

```
select [column1], [column2], [column3], [column4]
from
(
  select [column1], [column2], [column3], [column4],
    row_number() over(partition by column2, column3, column4 order by column1) rn
  from yourtable
) src
where rn <= 3
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2ba5a/3)